# How to solve the error "Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getNamespaces() on boolean"?

Tags: php

I am getting `Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getNamespaces () on boolean` error when using `simplexml_load_file`

This is the code of my function

```
protected function getXmldt($file_path)
    {
        $xml = simplexml_load_file($file_path); 
        $ns = $xml->getNamespaces(true);
        $xml->registerXPathNamespace('c', $ns['cdi']);
        $xml->registerXPathNamespace('t', $ns['tdd']);
        
        foreach ($xml->xpath('//cdi:Comp') as $cdiComp){ 
              return $cdiComp['TipComp'];
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: It means `simplexml_load_file()` failed, so it couldn't load or maybe find your file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in php doc (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php):

> simplexml_load_file returns an object of class SimpleXMLElement with properties containing the data held within the XML document, or FALSE on failure.

The path or file format are probably wrong and you get FALSE from your call.
That explains your error.